# Почему children для li закрывает Ul, в который он вложен? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Всем привет.
Код здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/4WQGY/

Смысл скрипта в том, чтобы если у нас есть вложенный ul, То мы открываем его и возвращаем false. Иначе, если ничего не вложено, открываем ссылку.

Ссылки работают как надо. Но я никак не пойму. Если в примере нажать "Кухни" и кликнуть - откроется следующий ul, и если в нем кликнуть на ссылку, где нет вложенного ul тот этот ul закроется. Почему так? Как исправить? Я уже голову сломал себе :)

Comment: Интересный вопрос! буду следить за ответами...
Я попробовал добавить обработчик onclick, но эффект остался тот же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu ul').hide();
    $('.menu li.current').parent().show();
    $('.menu li').has('ul').children('a').bind('click',function() {
        $(this).parent('li').children('ul').slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4WQGY/8/

Comment: Спасибо большое) Работает. А ведь до первой части я мог и сам догадаться) Но все равно знаний не хватает

Comment: Ещё можно `$(this).next('ul').slideToggle(300);`

Comment: Ну это понятно. Но не всегда с next выходит